# How to open warning/information/error dialog in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

How to open warning/information/error dialog in Swing?

I need standard error dialog with "Ok" button and "red cross" image.
I.e. analog of `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.openError()`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

See [How to Make Dialogs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

You can use:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Eggs are not supposed to be green.");
```

And you can also change the symbol to an error message or an warning. E.g see [JOptionPane Features](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features).

Comment: Make sure you dispose the frame, or pass null as the frame. If you don't it could hold your process open.

Answer (score 27):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ErrorDialog {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    String message = "\"The Comedy of Errors\"\n"
        + "is considered by many scholars to be\n"
        + "the first play Shakespeare wrote";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message, "Dialog",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
}
```

Comment: although this works this doesnt close the program once you hit ok 
can you add some info on that

Answer (score 9):

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
....
```

Have a look on this [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) on how to make dialogs.

Answer (score 4):

Just complementing, you can use static imports to give you a hand, making the code cleaner, like this:

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;

public class SimpleDialog(){
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        showMessageDialog(null, "Message", "Title", ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: plz if you are going to tell people something like "It's kind of obvious", just don't bother writing an answer. nobody knows the exact same things you do and neither does anybody have to.

Comment: this is literally my first SO post.

Comment: thx for editing the answer.